# Como executar uma procedure com output no php com driver mssql

Tags: php

Estou tentando executar uma procedure do sql server que me retorna uma variável.
A procedure, por exemplo tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TESTE
@ID INT,
@REFERENCIA INT OUTPUT
AS  
    SELECT @REFERENCIA = ID_REFERENCIA
    FROM REFERENCIA  WHERE ID_REFERENCIA = @ID;
    RETURN
GO
```

No SQL ManagementStudio, uso a seguinte consulta para me retornar o OUTPUT da minha SP:

```
DECLARE @REF INT
EXEC SP_TESTE 1,@REFERENCIA = @REF OUTPUT
SELECT @REF AS REFERENCIA
```

Agora gostaria de saber como passar essa consulta para ser executada no PHP, usando o driver para sql server, sqlsrv_query, por exemplo. Mas no sqlsrv_query só estou conseguindo executar uma instrução por vez.

Comment: Seria isso?

mssql_query('exec SP_TESTE @ExternalFieldID', $con);

Comment: Desculpe, escrevi errado, preciso do driver sqlsrv (tinha postado mssql por engano)... Aparentemente ele só me permite fazer uma execução por query...

Answer (score 1):

Faz com PDO que dá certo.

Abre a conexão:

```html
<?php

try {
    $con = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=$SERVIDOR;Database=$BANCO_DE_DADOS', $USUARIO, $SENHA );
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print_r('Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
}
```

Depois executa  a procedure e faça o que bem entender com os dados;

```html
$query = "exec SUA_PROCEDURE";

$prepare = $con->prepare($query);

$prepare->execute();

$result = $prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//abaixo só se precisar iterar pelo resultado, se não pode usar o array retornado em $result

foreach ($result as $r => $val) {
    $resultado[] = $val;
}
```

Se precisar com o driver em si, sem PDO:

Primeiro, abre a conexão:

```html
<?php

/**
 *
 * abre a conexao
 */
$con = sqlsrv_connect(
    'SERVIDOR',
    array(
        "UID"=>"USUARIO",
        "PWD"=>"SENHA",
        "Database"=>"BANCO_DE_DADOS",
        "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
    )
);

//testa a conexao
if( $con === false){
    echo "Conexao nao estabelecida: ";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
```

Depois executa a query:

```html
$query = "exec PROCEDURE";

$exec = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);

while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($exec, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
    print_r($r);
}
```

Mais um detalhe, dependendo do seu caso, se não der certo com nenhum dos métodos acima, será necessário usar [PDOStatement::nextRowset(void)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) ou [sqlsrv_next_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php).

A Microsoft tem [uma página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn865013(v=sql.105).aspx) só com a documentação do driver `SQLSRV`.

[Veja aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296196(v=sql.105).aspx) um exemplo de aplicação do driver.